# Float : right in css is not working

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in css. I'm trying to align my info icon in right side.

The HTML and CSS I have is below:

```css
   .content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar {
      height: 8%;
      width: 100%;
      box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #888888;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 10;
  }
  .content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar > #room-id {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
  }
    
  .content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar > #room-info {
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="chat-top-bar valign-wrapper">
    <p id="room-id"><b>Title</b></p>
    <i class="material-icons" id="room-info">info</i>
  </div>
```

Also I'm using materialize css..

I want the info icon to align in right side like this, but it is not working with the above css:

Complete Code : https://codepen.io/buckydroid/pen/rzRzrN

[image: Component Image]

Comment: You are floating an element with id `room-info`, but the icon has class `material-icons`

Comment: @FluffyKitten nvm I accidentally removed it while writing question...

Comment: can you provide the complete template include `.content`, `.chat-section`, `.chat-window`

Comment: You must have more to the HTML than you have included - the CSS is referencing ,content .chat-section and .chat-window elements. If you remove those classes from the CSS, the icon floats right. Can you include the rest of these classes from your code so we can see the issue?

Comment: @masterpreenz I have added complete code. Please check

Comment: @FluffyKitten I just added the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet lacks of parents with classes .content .chat-section .chat-window so it doesn't work.

```css
   .content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar {
      height: 8%;
      width: 100%;
      box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #888888;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 10;
  }
  .content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar > #room-id {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
  }
    
  .content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar > #room-info {
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="content">
    <div class="chat-section">
      <div class="chat-window">
        <div class="chat-top-bar valign-wrapper">
          <p id="room-id"><b>Title</b></p>
          <i class="material-icons" id="room-info">info</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Update**

The `.valign-wrapper` is a flex container so the floats don't work. You could remove the `display: flex;` or give the flex container `justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: Adding   justify-content: space-between in chat-top-bar fixed the problem. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

`p` tag is a `block` elements make it `inline-block` by adding `display:inline-block` property.

CSS

```
#room-id{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That won't fix the problem - the room-id paragraph is totally independent of the `<i>`element that the OP is trying to float

Comment: place the i tag inside p tag

Answer (score 0):

your `CSS` might not have been working at all

```
.content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar {
  height: 8%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #888888;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
}
.content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar > #room-id {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
}

.content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar > #room-info {
  float: right;
}
```

this `.chat-top-bar > #room-id` and this `.chat-top-bar > #room-info` might be true at all but that might not be the case of the parent selectors as `> first child selector` only selects first child elements which would be in this order:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="chat-section">
     <div class="chat-window">
       <div class="chat-top-bar valign-wrapper">
         <p id="room-id"><b>Title</b></p>
         <i class="material-icons" id="room-info">info</i>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if there is another container that wraps those your `.content > .chat-section > .chat-window > .chat-top-bar > #room-info` will fail. Just remove `>` you don't need it anyway.

Also, make `<p>` `display: inline-block` as `<p>` is a block element by default and block elements contains `100% width` by default.

hope that helps